# Spring MVC: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hello.jsp]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get started with Spring MVC & Tomcat, however I don't seem to be able to create single handler to render a minimalistic page.

The following files have been created:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="springapp" version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <display-name>Spring MVC Framework Test</display-name>
</web-app>
```

**springapp-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <!--<mvc:annotation-driven />-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="springapp.web.*"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/hello.jsp" class="springapp.web.HelloController"/>
</beans>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP Title</title>
</head>
<body>

${message}

</body>
</html>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package springapp.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Folder structure:

[image]

My attempts at finding the handler:

```
16-Aug-2016 16:31:18.867 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springapp/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'
16-Aug-2016 16:31:22.991 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springapp/web/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'
16-Aug-2016 16:31:23.023 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springapp/web/hello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springapp'
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from this line?  <bean name="/hello.jsp" class="springapp.web.HelloController"/>. No need to do this. and also this value="/hello.jsp" ?

Comment: You are right! Removing that line had no effect on the current situation.

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/hello.jsp" ... is wrong . should be @RequestMapping(value="/hello"...  if you tried this, please update your question

Comment: I dont see any vieuwresolver neither.

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte - changing the value didn't seem to do the trick. Pardon my ignorance but do I really need a viewresolver, if I have the prefix & suffix properties already set in **springapp-servlet.xml** ?

Comment: Actually, there are lots of unnecessary codes in your app. Just try this imple example here. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this :
Also you should run it using **/springapp/hello**  instead of **/springapp/hello.jsp**

Controller :

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public class HelloController{

       @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
          model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

          return "hello";
       }

    }
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="springapp.web" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

your jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Although, I'm still trying to find what you have changed to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see your folder structure and the springapp-servlet.xml, I think you have to put hello.jsp file inside of WEB-INF folder because it could be the reason why can't find the page (Maybe show this type of error 404). According with springapp-servlet.xml you are indicating your jsp file should be inside WEB-INF folder.

Comment: I have placed the file in the WEB-INF folder, but I am still getting a 404

Comment: I forgot say you need to declare this tag like this: <bean id= "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

Comment: Also I think this: <bean name="/hello.jsp" class="springapp.web.HelloController"/> should not be here, remove it.